# How to extend short logotype to full logo in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, transitions

I'm a beginner in AE I'd like to create a similar effect to this example but I'm not quite sure how to achieve the smooth transition from 'FU' to a full title. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a transition between a few layers of text and some shapes, probably with an Invert effect placed over all of it as an Adjustment Layer.

The smoothness comes from the [animating of the motion as curves](https://vimeo.com/68022971?embedded=true&source=video_title&owner=16970690).

This is a great free beginner's course to After Effects (even though it's quite old):
https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/